¿Como mantener centrados los elementos en kotlin mediante xml?
Tengo 2 paneles en un contenedor que se mantienen visibles los 2, pero quiero que si uno de estos paneles desaparece el otro se ubique en el centro del contenedor, como lo puedo hacer en kotlin en android obiviamente, solo usando el xml y no picando codigo, es posible? cual es el mejor layout a usar en este caso?
Estuve probando un rato y no encontre forma de hacerlo solo en xml, picando codigo solo haria que cambien las cadenas del layout y ya esta, pero que sentido tendria el layout entonces si tengo que estar modificandolo por codigo, no? o estoy confundidendo conceptos? en cualquier caso, se puede hacer algo así solo desde el XML, vi algo de los guidelines con lo que tal vez prodria hacerlo pero no lo logre.
ven estos son los 2 "paneles"

y asi deberian quedar si falta uno u el otro



Imagino no estas usando ConstraintLayout?

Lo solucione estaba linkeando mal los elementos, y debia agregar tambien un atributo que no conocia,dentro de la configuracion del constraintlayout de los elementos que es este

app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"

, adjunto como me quedo, por si a alguien le sirve
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/panel_opciones"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="202dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/interruptorFlash"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.687">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/panel_selector_color"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="147dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/panel_barras"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vista_color"
            android:layout_width="23dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/boton_arcoiris"
            android:layout_width="76dp"
            android:layout_height="77dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circulo_arcoiris"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:translationY="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/vista_color"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.813" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/etiqueta_color_luz"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:text="Color"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/boton_arcoiris"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/panel_barras"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/panel_selector_color"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel_intensidad"
            android:layout_width="221dp"
            android:layout_height="88dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/etiqueta_intensidad"
                android:layout_width="249dp"
                android:layout_height="31dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="Brillo"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.571"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
                android:id="@+id/barra_intensidad"
                android:layout_width="216dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:stepSize="1"
                android:valueFrom="1"
                android:valueTo="5"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etiqueta_intensidad"
                app:thumbColor="#03DAC5"
                app:thumbHeight="25dp"
                app:thumbRadius="12dp"
                app:tickColor="@color/black"
                app:trackColorActive="#03DAC5"
                app:trackColorInactive="#444444"
                app:trackHeight="25dp" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel_intermitencia"
            android:layout_width="221dp"
            android:layout_height="88dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/panel_intensidad"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            tools:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/etiqueta_intermitencia"
                android:layout_width="249dp"
                android:layout_height="31dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="Intermitencia"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.555"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
                android:id="@+id/barra_intermitencia"
                android:layout_width="216dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:stepSize="1"
                android:valueFrom="99"
                android:valueTo="1000"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.619"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etiqueta_intermitencia"
                app:thumbColor="#03DAC5"
                app:thumbHeight="25dp"
                app:thumbRadius="12dp"
                app:tickVisible="false"
                app:trackColorActive="#03DAC5"
                app:trackColorInactive="#444444"
                app:trackHeight="25dp" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

